# Forward a website out of a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, vmware

I'm connected via VPN to a testing environment on a linux virtual machine inside VMWare. On my host windows machine, I'd like to test a single website that the virtual machine has access to.

Is it possible to grant my host windows machine access to the website 10.2.53.6 that a virtual machine has access to over vpn?

Comment: Assuming you're using a VPN client to tunnel into the network, you should already have access to that IP address...

Comment: But the VPN tunnel is within the vitual machine. As of now the VM is sharing the host's IP and the VPN connection. I did try to connect from the host but it doesn't work (not very surprising).

Comment: So, the virtual machine is local?  And the VPN client is within the virtual machine?

Comment: correct. This is because the supplied VPN certs were written for linux machines

Comment: Easiest way to do this?  Probably ask for Windows VPN certs.

Comment: If you can reach the linux virtual machine from the windows host (by the virtual machine IP, for example) you could port forward that site through SSH to one of your linux ports... If that's possible, tell me that I explain how that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need a port forwarding application, within the virtual machine.

Lets say the vm's external ip is a.b.c.d.

You will set up the port forwarding application to listen on a.b.c.d, port 80, and FORWARD all traffic to the website the VM has access to (as described).

Then point your host to http://a.b.c.d:80